# Create NuGet Package using MSBuild and VS Team Services

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, azure-devops

I am using visual studio 2015, from past few days I was trying to create nuget package that are hosted on Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) and created every time a project is build, but with no success. Can someone please provide step by step intro to how to achieve this task. I am very thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Following is a simple build definition to create nuget package and publish the package to VSTS hosted package service:

1. Create a build definition in VSTS to build the project.
2. Add "NuGet Packager" task in the build definition to create the Nuget package. I use project file to generate the nuget package, so set the path to "NugetP.csproj".
   [image]
3. Add "NuGet Publisher" task to publish the package to Feed. Since I use the VSTS hosted package feed, so choose "Internal NuGet Feed", and enter the nuget feed URL in "Internal Feed URL".
   [image]
4. Save the build definition and queue a new build. The nuget package will be created and pushed to the feed.
   [image]